# excluding subdomain from root .htaccess Rewrite_rule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got Opencart script on my website. in root .htaccess, I have these lines to seo links.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have a subdomain named /imei but I can't have access to it (i'm getting 404 Not Found). The reason is the last line of above code. If I delete this line I can have access to /imei but Seo will be disabled for shop.

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

My question is that how can I exclude RewriteRule in /imei? I've tried several types of htaccess in /imei .htaccess so far but didn't work!

Any ideas will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're talking about an `imei` folder at your web root.

In that case, change your last rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!imei)([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The `(?!imei)` is a negative lookahead that checks that the path doesn't start with `imei`

Let me know if this works. :)

Comment: I changed it but Didn't work(still getting page not found). yes, /imei is a folder at web root. Do I need to create a .htaccess in /imei?

Comment: @PersianHero No, the htaccess is fine at the web root, no need for one in the `imei` folder. Can you give me an example of address that gives  you a 404? (Change the domain of course.)

Comment: @PersianHero: This should have worked for you. As an alternative create a new `/imei/.htaccess` file with just one line `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: I just realised what the problem is. I'm using htaccess password protection in /IMEI. Whether I change RewriteRule to @zx81's one or not, I'm getting "Page Not Found". I must disable that line in root's .htaacess!
Any ideas?